Virtual volume stored on a RAIDZ pool takes twice the amount of space as it should
I have a Proxmox server with 24 4T nvme drives. I have created a RAIDZ pool called Media3 which is about 84T in total usable space. I have setup a virtual host and added a second virtual disk to the virtual host which I have allocated 55T of space and specified Media3 as the storage for the virtual drive. I copied 1T of data into the virtual drive. The virtual drive reports 1T used. However, on the Proxmox side, I see that 2T have been used on Media3. I dumped 27T of files into the virtual drive, and it shows 27T used. However Media3 reports 54T used. When I delete 1T from the virtual disk, 2T is removed from Media3. My big question is why? I took great pains to set this up so that compression is enabled, the virtual disk is connected over scsi with discard enabled and SSD emulation enabled. Can anyone help me figure this out? One solution which is the wrong one is to just make the virtual drive 40T, but that is not efficient.
What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.
